# Problem with package gmp (or with xkeyval?)

Tags: graphics, metapost, xkeyval

I use the "gmp" package which allows to insert MetaPost coding (placed inside an `mpost` or `mpost*` environment) in a LaTeX source file. In few words, it does approximately the same job as other packages like "emp" or "mpgraphics", with additional features that are not relevant here.

In particular, "gmp" defines as an (xkeyval-type) option key named `everymp` which is supposed to contain some code to be inserted at the beginning of each MetaPost files produced. Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[everymp= {input boxes;}]{gmp}
\begin{document}
\begin{mpost*}
    % here the MetaPost code
\end{mpost*}
\end{document}
```

Here the `everymp` key contains the metapost instruction `input boxes ;` which is thus supposed to be inserted at the beginning of the MetaPost file produced by the compilation. But what I obtain is different:

```
%% Do not edit, this file has been generated
%% automatically by bug-everymp.tex via gmp.sty

inputboxes;
outputtemplate:= "%j.mps";
beginfig(1);

endfig;
end.
```

As you can see, the line `input boxes;` has become `inputboxes;` which means nothing to MetaPost…

I have found what triggers this bug, but this makes it weirder still: it comes from the space inserted between `=` and `{input boxes;}` in the option declaration:

```
everymp= {input boxes;}
```

If I suppress this space, i.e. if I write

```
everymp={input boxes;}
```

I obtain

```
input boxes ;
```

in the MetaPost, i.e. what is expected.

Of course this problem is not very important, but it puzzles me. How come that a space character inserted between `=` and its argument can produce that behaviour? Is it a problem with the gmp package, or with the (x)keyval package? In the latter case it should have been noticed elsewhere, but until now I haven't found something similar.

I am using the MacTeX 2012 distribution (i.e. TeX Live 2012) on Mac OS X Snow Leopard (10.6.8), and the gmp package in its first and so far only version (1.0).

Comment: Puzzling indeed. I guess it depends somehow on `xkeyval`.

Comment: The `gmp` package just delegates the absorption of the value to `xkeyval` and missing braces or a space before the opening brace results in getting `inputboxes;` as `#1`. :(

Comment: If I do the same with the `mpsettings` option of the 'mpost(*)' environment, i.e if I write  `[mpsettings= {input boxes;}]`I get `input boxes;` in the mp file, as expected. Really, I don't understand…

Comment: The problem seems to be in bad interaction with the working of `\usepackage`; if I use `\gmpoptions{...}` after `\usepackage{gmp}` the problem does not show. Actually `\usepackage` uses `\zap@spaces` that is quite drastic in the way it works.

Comment: Thanks! You're certainly right. Ahmed Musa's answer confirms it, by the way.

Comment: In my opinion it's best to use only the "main" options in the `\usepackage` line and to set the others with `\gmpoptions`. Nice to know another user of the package. ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The space between `input` and `boxes;` is removed by the LaTeX kernel, not by xkeyval package. We see that here:

```
\@pass@ptions #1#2#3->\expandafter \xdef \csname opt@#3.#1\endcsname {\@ifundef
ined {opt@#3.#1}\@empty {\csname opt@#3.#1\endcsname ,}\zap@space #2 \@empty }
#1<-\@currext 
#2<-everymp=input boxes;
#3<-gmp
```

A solution: load the *catoptions* package before `\usepackage[everymp=input boxes;]{gmp}`. Then there will be no need to wrap `input boxes;` in braces.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{catoptions}
\usepackage[everymp=input boxes;]{gmp}

\begin{document}
\begin{mpost*}
    % here the MetaPost code
\end{mpost*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot, I would never have been able to figure it out by myself.